# How to use DL Query programmatically

Tags: java, owl, protege, dlquery

I would like to know whether I can use DL Query in Protege programatically. Is it possible to enter a query in Java and retrieve individuals like how it is done in SQL?

E.g. query is `hasCalorificContentValue value 723` and I would like to retrieve an individual called `QuattroFormaggio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an OWL file then you can use the [OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) to programatically access, edit and query your ontology without having to use Protege. On the [OWLAPI examples page](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/2.x.x/documentation.html) there are code examples that describe how you would encode your query.